# OrmLite. SELECT column_name AS name

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I need to execute query:

```
SELECT uid as _id 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

How can I do this with OrmLite?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the [DatabaseField](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html) annotation:

```
@DatabaseName("MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable{
   @DatabaseField(columnName = "uid")
   int _id;
}
```

See the [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#DaoManager) for more